# How to apply Powerbi Embedded advanced filters that use dates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have an angular 1.5 application that is using the power bi embedded js library to instantiate advanced filters and then applying it to an embedded report via the setFilters() function:

reportsCtrl.js

```
function onEmbedded(report) {
    vm.embededReport = report;
    if (vm.activeFilter) {
        vm.embededReport.setFilters([vm.activeFilter]);
    }
}

function buildFilter() {
    var date1 = new Date(vm.selectedDate.toDateString());
    var date2 = new Date(date1);

    //add one day via mutator setDate function
    date2.setDate(date1.getDate() + 1);

    vm.activeFilter = new pbi.models.AdvancedFilter(
        {
            table: 'tblMessage',
            column: 'event_timestamp'
        },
        'And',
        [{
            operator: 'GreaterThanOrEqual',
            value: date1
        },
        {
            operator: 'LessThan',
            value: date2
        }]
    );

    if (vm.embededReport) {
        vm.embededReport.setFilters([vm.activeFilter]);
    }
}

function loadReport(reportId) {
    vm.reportConfig = null;
    reportService.getReport(reportId, facilityId).then(function (response) {
        //merge report with default configurations
        vm.reportConfig = angular.merge({}, defaultReportConfig, response);
    });
}
```

reports.tpl.html

```
<h1>{{vm.message}}</h1>
<div ng-repeat="report in vm.reports">
   <pre>{{report | json}}</pre>
   <button ng-click="vm.loadReport(report.id)">embed</button>
</div>
<button ng-click="vm.buildFilter()">
    Add Filter
</button>

<h2>Acitve Filter!</h2>
<pre>{{vm.activeFilter | json}}</pre>
<div>
   <powerbi-component ng-if="vm.reportConfig" options="vm.reportConfig" on-embedded="vm.onEmbedded($embed)" ></powerbi-component>
</div>
```

I get the following 3 errors when the filter is applied.

- ".operator is invalid. Not meeting required constraint"
- ".conditions.0.value is invalid. Not meeting type constraint"
- "filter is invalid"

Judging from the [documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Filters) though I think my filter is structured correctly... any ideas? I feel like its something small I am missing..

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out eventually. Posting the answer here in case it helps anyone else out. Dates in filter objects from the powerbi embedded library have to be formatted like this:

"2016-12-01T18:52:11.148Z"

With the javascript date object .toISOString() or .toJSON() will do the trick.